# Install Ubuntu 15.10 on Dell XPS 15 2015 9550 with Nvidia 960

Tags: nvidia, 15.10, dell, windows-10, xps

I am trying to do this installation and tried almost everything but ended up freezing before even language selection. The latest I tried based on an advise from a nice guy in this forum is below, any further thoughts or experience with this specific machine?

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media.
Highlight Try Ubuntu without installing.
Press the E key.
Add nouveau.modeset=0 to the end of the linux line.
Press the F10 key to boot to the Live desktop.

Start the installation of the Ubuntu system.

When finished boot the installed system.
Highlight the Ubuntu GRUB menu entry.
Press the E key.
Add nouveau.modeset=0 to the end of the linux line.
Press the F10 key to boot the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1.
Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot

Answer (score -1):

When you reboot with "sudo reboot" as the last command there, you have to add Nouveau.modeset=0 to grub again.

See this great guide:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2301071

It mentions how to make set nouveau.modeset permanently, once you've installed ubuntu.