# How to safely install Ubuntu alongside existing Windows 10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi

My main device is a Dell XPS 15 9550 laptop (6700HQ - 16GB RAM - 512 SSD NVMe).

My SSD partitions:

[image: Disk Management Screenshot]

I have 2 partitions. C for Windows 10 and D for my files. I'm thinking of shrinking the drive D (currently it has about 100GB free space, but I can clear more files to get more than 150GB free space).

Is there is a tutorial that can help me to install Ubuntu beside Windows 10 without losing any exciting data and allowing me to access the files from my NTFS partitions "C and D" ?

Laptop uses: UEFI + Secure boot + AHCI + Fastboot: Thorough.

Comment: Some Dell specific threads. http://askubuntu.com/questions/884991/ubuntu-16-10-dual-boot-error-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install & http://askubuntu.com/questions/867488/dell-xps-13-9360-dualboot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1344306_867488 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2345444 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/736613/install-ubuntu-15-10-on-dell-xps-15-2015-9550-with-nvidia-960

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the simplest and safest method that has worked for me:

1. Create a bootable USB drive [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). Be sure to select "GPT partition scheme for UEFI" before writing to the drive. Other similar tools are available but for me, they didn't work with UEFI
   [image: Keep every option as shown is image]
2. [Turn off fast startup in windows](https://in.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/37059). It'll let you access your drives in Ubuntu and other distros.
3. Turn off secure boot. Check your BIOS, you can turn it off there.
4. Boot into the USB stick. You can usually do this by pressing F9 key during startup though, it varies from computer to computer.
5. Don't begin directly installing Ubuntu yet, run **gparted** from menu and,
   Shrink your drive, create a new partition less or equal to your RAM size and format it as swap.
   Create another drive from the space left and format it as ext4
   Close the gparted window
6. Begin ubuntu install
   [**AT INSTALLATION TYPE, SELECT SOMETHING ELSE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KURnS.png)
7. Select your previously creates ext4 partition and set the following options:
   Use as: ext4 journaling file system
   Mount point: \
8. Let the rest be default and continue with install.
9. You should now be able to dual-boot

Comment: Thank you.

Will I be able to access my files on the NTFS partitions D and C?

Comment: If you followed the Step 2 correctly, you'll have the access

Comment: Thank You.. This worked great for me. I resized the partitions using **Easeus** free edition from windows instead  of **gparted**. Windows Disk Manager didn't allow me to shrink the partitions to the needed size.